# Values are not equal when they should be

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a snippet of code that is asking for user input. The issue is the evaluation of the current month. If the current month is input, gooddate should = 0. For some reason they are not evaluating as equal. I tried making the variables integers as well as strings, but 08 doesn't equal 08 for the current month for some reason. Let me know if isn't clear enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
month = str(time.strftime("%m"))

# User Input
print("""Starting Time
Time format - Month/Day Hours:Minutes - Example 7/21 08:00
Option - Leave month out, but keep /  - Example  /21 08:00""")
date1 = input("Enter Starting Time ->  ",)

# Split /
x = date1.split('/')

# Evaluate if the current month is what the user entered.
print("x Value=", x[0])
print("month Value=", month)

if month == x[0]:
    gooddate1 = 0
else:
    start_replacement1 = month+date1
gooddate1 = 1

print("gooddate Value=", gooddate1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you forgot to indent the second last line: `gooddate1 = 1`. So right now `gooddate1` will aways be 1 instead of 0.

You can use `==`. `if month == x[0]` is a fine way to compare strings.

Comment: Improper indentation was the cause of the issue after all. Thanks for everyone's help.  I am very new at Python, so just beginning to learn.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison in Python is not that easy as what you did (`if month == x[0]`). But you can do it with the keyword `in` as a workaround:

```
if month in x[0]:
    gooddate1 = 0
```

(and you have to index your `gooddate1`, otherwise it's not in the `else` case, and `gooddate` will always be 1.)

Comment: Actually, it is that easy. `if month in x[0]` is very different than `if month == x[0]`

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. The problem was only with the wrong indentation.